# How to use TypeScript definitions in PhpStorm 10 for autocomplete suggestions

Tags: npm, tsconfig, typescript1.7, phpstorm-10

Is there a way to tell `PhpStorm 10` where the `TypeScript definition` files are using `tsconfig.json` so it would use them for autocomplete suggestions?

I've installed npm package @types/jquery.

`npm install --save @types/jquery`

- PhpStorm 10
- TypeScript compiler v1.7.3 (bundled)
- Node v6.10.3

For actual compiling I'm using Webpack and TypeScript 2.0

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/documentation-look-up-in-external-javascript-libraries.html

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for